# Given any $r \in \mathbb Q$, there is $m \in \mathbb Z$ such that $m \le r < m + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Suppose the set $S$ contains all $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n > r$ for any $r \in \mathbb Q$. By Archimedes, there are some $m, n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n > r > m$ for any $r \in \mathbb Q$. So $S$ is non-empty and contains the least element. Let $n(?)$ be that element. Suppose $m > r$. Then $m \in S$. But $m < n$. Contradiction. So, $m \le  r < n + 1$.

Does it make sense? If not, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a rational number $r$ consider $m=\lfloor r \rfloor$. This is the largest integer which is less than or equal to $r$. Of course, $m\le r< m+1$.

Comment: What if we are required to use the Archimedian property and the well-ordering property? How can that be done? Thanks.

Comment: As you wrote. For any given $r$ there is an integer $n=m+1$ with $r<m+1$ by Archimedes. Now take the smallest one (assuming that $r$ is positive). Then $m\le r<m+1$. This means $m=\lfloor r \rfloor$.

Comment: I am having some difficulty with all this. What are the parts in my proof that I need to fix? For example, I am not sure if we can allow $n$ to be the least element.

Comment: Why not ? The set $S$ should be $S=\{ n\in \mathbb{Z}\mid n>r\}$. Your definition of $S$ is unclear.